# Find all dates within a specific month in multiple tabs

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-indirect

I have a shared (hence **no VB or macros**) Excel file with multiple (100+) tabs. There are different dates (`dd.mm.yyyy`) in column C in every sheet.
In the first sheet there is a list (tagged "the_list") of all sheet names.
Have to find a SUM of all instances per month, e.a. January,2014 (E1) - xxx, February, 2014 (E2) - yyy, ... March, 2015 (Ez) - zzz.
I have tried using EOMONTH, but it counts only those dates with the last day of the month in them, e.a. `31.01.2015` and not `30.01.2015`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&the_list&"'!C:C"),EOMONTH(E1,0)))
```

Would prefer not to create/hide another column in every tab with `=EOMONTH(C1,0)` as it adds yet another point of failure due to multiple users.

Comment: It's 2007. I was hoping to insert the same EOMONTH somewhere in the above formula, just couldn't figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&the_list&"'!A:A"),">="&E1,INDIRECT("'"&the_list&"'!A:A"),"<"&E2))
```

Comment: This should work. Will need to check at work as my home Mac Excel version decided to refuse accepting cell format as dates (and nothing works as a result..).

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&the_list&"'!C:C"),">="&E1,INDIRECT("'"&the_list&"'!C:C"),"<"&EOMONTH(E1,0)))
```

This has solved it, thanks

Comment: That should be `...,"<="&EOMONTH(E1, 0)` which will still only work if the dates do not contain times or `...,"<"&EDATE(E1, 1)` which should work all of the time.